# How can i fix this type of error?

Tags: reactjs

Hello everybody i'm working on react application and when i start it it shows me this type of error [image: here]
i'm working with dnd react http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/
can you help me ? and thanks in advance

and this is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "dndexercice",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.3.1",
        "react-dnd": "^2.6.0",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.6.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
        "eslint": "^3.19.0",
        "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ran the commands:
`npm install --save react-dnd` and 
`npm install --save react-dnd-html5-backend`?

Comment: @RonNabuurs of course npm install --save react-dnd and
npm install --save react-dnd-html5-backend

Comment: Enable eslint. It should give you the error in vs code if you have the plugin installed. Then you can debug more easily, because it looks like something goes wrong when building and including dnd.

Comment: how can i enable it ?

Comment: Follow the instructions in the console from your last image

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the ES7 decorator syntax (`@`) you need to add the [transform-decorators plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/) to your babel transpiler.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators
```

In `.babelrc` :

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators"]
}
```

Comment: i have installed it but the file .babelrc where i found it ? in the project file? i want to set the option in the workspace not only in this project

Comment: If you're already using babel it should be in the root of your project folder. Note that if you use `create-react-app` you may want to eject in order to use decorators(there's also some [workarounds without ejecting](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/214))

Comment: If you don't get decorators to work you can still use the ES6 syntax (click ES6 on top of dnd docs code snippets) you'll see the ES6 HOC syntax.